# Getting exception when configuring dataSource in redshift databse using spring-batch

Tags: spring-batch, amazon-redshift

my datasource configuration is :

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:redshift://spx....redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/spx");
dataSource.setUsername("spx");
dataSource.setPassword("*****");
```

**Getting exception : -**

```
2017-10-06 15:58:58.670  INFO 5560 --- [           main] .s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer : Jetty started on port(s) 8080 (http/1.1) 
2017-10-06 15:58:58.670  INFO 5560 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2017-10-06 15:58:58.670  INFO 5560 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2017-10-06 15:58:58.749  INFO 5560 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
```

2017-10-06 15:58:59.796  INFO 5560 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-06 15:58:59.802 ERROR 5560 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
at com.spring.batch.redshift.example.BatchApp.main(BatchApp.java:22) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: "batch_job_seq" is not a sequence;
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(AbstractSequenceMaxValueIncrementer.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:108) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]



Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: "batch_job_seq" is not a sequence;
at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

**This datasource is working fine without spring-batch**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was jobRepository databaseType= that has to match with the dataSource= scripts

Comment: is there support for redshift + spring batch. because we can not create sequence in redshift but spring batch is searching a sequence in data base whenever starting the app

Comment: In your case, you will have to find which DB is closest to redshift or even update existing scripts to work accordingly for redshift, there are so many ready to use scripts in org/springframework/batch/core/schema-*.sql in spring-core library.

Comment: DB closest to redshift is postgresql. but in postgresql we can create sequece.

Comment: and in my application  also postgresql script execute